# add text to src of an image

Tags: jquery, image

Hi I need a jQuery function to add a text to src of all images in the page.
for example after one minute of load of my page I want to add `"mobileserver"` to src of all images like this.

```
<img src="mobileserver/images/sampleimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: I want to change images in my site one minute after it loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JQUERY ANSWER**
As Wolff stated there no point in using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('img').each(function () {
            var nSrc= 'mobileserver/' + $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', nSrc);
        });
    }, 60000);
});
```

**EDIT**
Since my answer wasn't fully correct, I'm trying to deserve these points, so here it is a pure javascript solution:

```
(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var imgTag = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
            count = imgTag.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            imgTag[i].setAttribute("src", 'mobileserver/' + imgTag[i].getAttribute('src'));
        }
    }, 60000);
})();
```

The only problem could be the browser compatibility, check this answer for other method to check if the document is ready:https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/1139052

Comment: Why not using a timeout? What is the purpose of `$(this).text(nSrc);`?

Comment: Oops sorry, I was trying with `a` tag andI wanted to check the link by printing it

Comment: About `setInterval` vs `setTimeout`...if I don't remember wrong with the second one the machine waits untill the function is executed, this doesn't happen with `setInterval`

Comment: No the only difference is that a timeout callback runs only once :)

Comment: Well you are right and I was partially right, `setInterval` doesn't care if the previous task has finished or not before run the second one, `setInterval` is less reliable with short intervals

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** to set delay and **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** with callback function for updating the `src` attribute,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
        $('img').attr('src',function (i,v) {
            return 'mobileserver/' + v;
        });
    }, 60000);
});
```